# Settings randomly not available

Tags: c#, tabs, settings

I've just started with Visual C#, with surprising success, however now I've run into an issue, that drives me crazy.

This problem applies to everything I've tried to write and I've not yet managed to formulate a successful Google search to answer my question.

I like to use the tabs Form, various tabs that to the "work" plus one Tab which contains a bunch of textboxes with the config data, like servername, logins, and so on.

I've also managed to save my settings using the builtin Settings feature.

Now here's my problem:
I launch the application, access the settings tab, enter my settings, close the application. When i restart the application all my previous settings are retained. So far so good.

However, these textboxes which always contain the correct info whenever i click on my settingstab, return an empty string when accessed by a method.
This behaviour is completely random, i launch the application, settings can be accessed, i close it, restart it settings are gone, next time they're there then gone again.

BUT, if i access the settings Tab, prior to running a method everything is fine.

Does this make an sense to anyone?
All i do is define application settings and assign them to my textboxes in the settings tab and save them with  `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` when the form is closed.
I've tried manually loading them with the form ie: `setSQLServer.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.setSQLServer;`
but the behaviour stays the same. A method run, prior to me clicking on the settings tab, randomly receives an empty string. When that happens all textboxes from the settings tab return empty strings.

Comment: Web, winforms, WPF or ... application ? When a method gets setting, what is the source (config class, textboxes, file ,...) ?

Comment: In this method, do you grab the string from the settings or from the textbox? If you grab it from the textbox, the string might not be in the textbox before you actually navigate to its tab.

Comment: I grab it from the textbox. The strange thing is, that it is randomly not available. However if i add: if (setsomeText.Text == "")
                Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();  it works fine :D Its a Windows Forms Application.

Comment: just tried to build a demo app to demonstrate the issue, of course in the demo everything works fine :D I guess when things work randomly there seems to be an issie with timing.

Comment: Properties.Settings.Default.Reload() worked for a short while only :D

Comment: currenlty this.texbox.text instead of textbox.text works, lets see for how long. @all: Thanks for your input.